# ASDF System Configuration Variables?

Tags: common-lisp, asdf

Is there a way to make a configurable ASDF system that loads different lisp files depending on user configuration variables?
Preferably, the loading process would fail with a legible error message if a required config var was not provided.
How would one set such variables conveniently when loading the system? (Manually, through quicklisp, or from another system definition file)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please do not use #+ and #- in the defsystem form, but :if-feature instead.

Also, it's much better to do runtime-differentiation or to have a different system target altogether depending on features than to have a target that changes its meaning in an unaccountable way that the build system can't see.

Comment: didn't know about :if-feature, guess I should rtfm one of this days

Comment: @Faré, could you elaborate on what you mean by changing the target in a way the build system can't see? Do you mean that reloading the system with new config vars could result in required files not being compiled?

Comment: Since there doesn't seem to be a clean and safe way to do it, and there's only one variable in my case anyway, I'll just go with your suggestion of using two different system definitions.

Answer (score 2):

Not out of the box but you could arrange something akin to that. The easiest way to change files a system loads would be using #+/- in combination with `*features*`.

One way to add features would be in .sbclrc (or your implementations startup file) if you want something more project specific you could define a perform :before load-op on your system that would call a function that would read a file and depending on its content's it could modify `*features*` so that different  components are read. I use this scheme for loading variables with configuration files.

So if my system is foo

```
(defsystem #:foo
  ...
  :dependencies (#:foo-config)
 ...)

(defmethod perform :after ((op load-op)
                           (system (eql (find-system :foo-config))))
  (asdf/package:symbol-call :foo/config-loader 'load-config
                            (system-relative-pathname :foo-config
                                                      #P"foo.config")))
```

Because #+/- works at read-time I'm guessing it wouldn't work because the features would be modified after reading the system definition. A hacky way around this could be to just require the config system and make the after method require the system after setting up the features.

My 2c.